# Remove duplicates in dictionary and leave only min values

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, duplicates

I have dictionary of type `[Int:[String:String]]`

Example:

> [1546696330: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531017: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531031: ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"]]

As you can see I have 2 repeated dictionaries with key `symbol` with value is `ETH`. I need code that will remove all values and leave the min (Int) value.

Expected result:

> [1546531017: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531031: ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"]]

where is `1546531017 < 1546696330`

Comment: You have nested dictionaries, and it looks like you want to collapse duplicate entries in the inner dictionary, but it isn't clear how that collapse should be driven. How did you decide to keep the outer key `1546531017` in your result, vs the other `1546696330` key?

Comment: How do you decide if there is a duplicate?  Is it just that the `symbol` matches, or do both the `symbol` and `amount` have to match to be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @DuncanC I need the minimum key and remove all others containing the duplicated symbol.

Comment: @vacawama the `amount` doesn't matter. I need to remove all where the symbol is duplicated and left the minimum one.

Comment: I'd go with a construction a dictionary where key are symbols and value is a "Int". If exists, replace when needed (if it's min than the current one). Then, keep only the values, and filter the dict (either remove the unused one, or construct a new one from the kept keys).  With no high level Swift function, to explain my logic: https://pastebin.com/gprc23X0

Comment: @Larme, that is exactly the approach I was going to use.  Why not make that an answer?

Comment: I was in a hurry and din’t had time to post a full answer. Also I made a solution not really Swifty, how an Obj-C dev would have done. I was looking also into a making one morr Swifty if possible, but did’t got time. You can answer it if you want. I might find later a more Swifty approach, but didn’t know the knowledge level of the author.

Comment: @Larme, I added an answer including making it more Swifty.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove duplicates with larger int values

```
let dict:[Int:[String:String]] = [ 1546531017: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531031: ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"],1546696330: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"]]
var dict2:[Int:[String:String]] = [:]

dict.forEach({ (key, value) in
    if let item = dict2.first(where: {value["symbol"] == $1["symbol"]}) {
        if (key < item.key) {
            dict2[item.key] = nil
            dict2[key] = value
        }
    } else {
        dict2[key] = value
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm described by @Larme in the comments is the straightforward way to approach this problem.

Create a `[String:Int]` dictionary that represents the values from the original dictionary you want to keep.  The *key* is the *symbol* and the *value* is the `Int` you want to keep.

Then use this dictionary to construct the final dictionary by using the values of `keep` to select the entries from the original dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
// original dictionary
let dict: [Int:[String:String]] = [1546696330: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531017: ["symbol": "ETH", "amount": "1.0"], 1546531031: ["symbol": "XRP", "amount": "200.0"]]

// Dictionary mapping symbol to Int of values we want to keep
var keep = [String:Int]()

// Loop on original dictionary deciding on whether to keep this symbol
// based on how its Int compares to the one we've already kept
for (key, value) in dict {
    guard let symbol = value["symbol"] else { continue }
    if let ekey = keep[symbol] {
        // We already have this one, so keep the minimum of the two
        keep[symbol] = min(key, ekey)
    } else {
        keep[symbol] = key
    }
}

// Show the keep dictionary
print(keep)
```

> ```
> ["XRP": 1546531031, "ETH": 1546531017]
> ```

```
// The final dictionary
var dict2 = [Int:[String:String]]()

// Fill the final dictionary based upon the values we chose to keep
for value in keep.values {
    dict2[value] = dict[value]
}

// Show the final result
print(dict2)
```

> ```
> [1546531031: ["amount": "200.0", "symbol": "XRP"], 1546531017: ["amount": "1.0", "symbol": "ETH"]]
> ```

---

**Creating `keep` with `reduce(into:)`:**

A little more Swifty if a bit less readable is to use `reduce(into:)` to create the `keep` dictionary:

```
let keep: [String:Int] = dict.reduce(into: [:]) {
    guard let symbol = $1.value["symbol"] else { return }
    $0[symbol] = min($0[symbol, default: $1.key], $1.key)
}
```

---

**Creating the final dictionary with `filter()`:**

Alternatively, you can create the final dictionary in one line by filtering the original one like so:

```
let dict2 = dict.filter { keep.values.contains($0.key) }
```

Comment: This method of creating the `keep` dictionary is likely to be more efficient than the accepted answer because it allows for direct lookup of duplicates which is O(1) instead of using `first(where:)` to find a duplicate which is O(n).  This would matter more as the size of the dictionary grows.